# Store array response as object inside array for options

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

**I would like to been appending objects to `instagram` value instead of overwriting them if there is a new object that isn't repeated**.

So I have this piece of code:

```
if (is_array($api_return)) {

    $api_return += ['last_updated' => time()];
    $this->instagram->set_user_id($api_return['user_id']);
    $this->instagram->set_username($api_return['username']);
    $this->instagram->set_access_token($api_return['access_token']);
    $this->instagram->set_access_token_expiration($api_return['access_token_expiration']);
    $this->instagram->set_last_updated($api_return['last_updated']);

    // Show our authenticated message.
    $page_content .= $this->get_admin_notice_content('green',
        'auth-finished', $this->instagram->get_username());

    update_option('instagram', $api_return);
}
```

What this does, is it takes `$api_return` which is a array and groups it into an object and saves it inside the database as this:

We have `option_name` which is `instagram` and then the value is:

```
a:5:{s:8:"username";s:16:"saint";s:7:"user_id";i:17841404774727369;s:12:"access_token";s:141:"IGQVJVR1N*****";s:23:"access_token_expiration";i:1650688769;s:12:"last_updated";i:1645536110;}
```

[image]

---

What I'm attempting to do:

Now I want to be able to save multiple object where the instagram key doesn't get overwritten but each new api_return gets stored as a new object if it's not the same in an array.

Here is an example:

```
authenticated_users = [
 {s:8:"username";s:16:"saint";s:7:"user_id";i:17841404774727369;s:12:"access_token";s:141:"IGQVJVR1N*****";s:23:"access_token_expiration";i:1650688769;s:12:"last_updated";i:1645536110;} 
 {s:8:"username";s:16:"test3";s:7:"user_id";i:17841404774727369;s:12:"access_token";s:141:"IGQVJVR1N*****";s:23:"access_token_expiration";i:1650688769;s:12:"last_updated";i:1645536110;}
];
```

What is the best approach on storing the option value as an array with multiple objects?

Comment: Sorry it  is not 100% clear to me what you are trying to do.  You want to store some data if they are unique, right? Why are they overwritten in the first place?

Comment: @mapawa on each $api_return, I get back an array which is saved as an object in the database, I would like to save it as an array instead and store an object inside that array and each time api_return runs with something new, keep storing new objects inside the array.

Comment: So you basically want to store an ever-growing text file of serialized php-arrays in the database? That is surely not the best, not even a good approach. Why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: I'm looking at building multi account support for instagram, so I'm looking to store `authenticated_users` as an array with multiple objects inside the array stored as object which is each individual account that was returned by `$api_return` which is the array Instagram provides.

Comment: @mapawa would you recommend another method?

Comment: At first glance, I would recommend you to create a table in the database with columns according to the array keys and simply insert every object into the database. Duplicate entries can be avoided by making the columns in the database unique.

Comment: Since this is wordpress, it's all being saved into the wp_options database table, so I don't think that would be possible for me, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: That might be case per default, but can't you just save it in any other database table?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first load the option an then manually merge the values:

```php
$current = get_option("instagram", []);

$newData = [
  $api_return,
];

// Merge array $current and $newData into single array so 
// $api_return is appended to $current and the option is updated.
update_option("instagram", array_merge($current, $newData));
```

Comment: Would this overwrite the update_option on each new $api_return, since we are setting it to an empty array? I'm looking to keep appending new objects to the option and getting the value.

Comment: @user17997251 Thats what its supposed to to.  Thats why you merge the values.

Comment: @user17997251 who is setting what to an empty array? `[]` in `get_option` is only the default value to use if that option does not exist in the database yet. And `$newData = [];` is of course _supposed_ to be a new array, that is the new "row" of data you want to insert (of course you will have to fill it with some data first.)

Comment: Let me give it a shot and double check! Thanks so much!

Comment: If I want the array to have a key such as 'authenticated_users', which would be the right approach on that?